# How does systemctl schedule system shutdown?

Tags: linux, shutdown, systemd, runlevel, systemctl

When I type `shutdown -h +30`, Linux somehow schedules runlevel's change within 30 minutes. On Debian, `/sbin/shutdown` is symbolic link to `/bin/systemctl`. My tests indicate that [`shutdown`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html) does *not* use neither [cron](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron) nor [systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers).

How does system shutdown is implemented by `systemd`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question. I tried what I now realise you must have tried- scheduling a shutdown and querying the systemd timers!

That showed that the shutdown was not in the systemd timers, as you noted. So then a quick perusal of the systemctl source gives us this call, as part of `halt_main()`:

```
r = sd_bus_call_method(
                       b,
                       "org.freedesktop.login1",
                       "/org/freedesktop/login1",
                       "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager",
                       "ScheduleShutdown",
                       &error,
                       NULL,
                       "st",
                       arg_action == ACTION_HALT     ? "halt" :
                       arg_action == ACTION_POWEROFF ? "poweroff" :
                       arg_action == ACTION_KEXEC    ? "kexec" :
                                                       "reboot",
                       arg_when);
```

*([systemctl.c line 7387](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L7387))*

So it would appear that shutdowns are handled by [`logind`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html). You can continue to pursue the details if you like- see [`login-dbus.c`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/281d4a7710b861559f11023657e661511d524ba0/src/login/logind-dbus.c). There are methods there for scheduling, cancelling, managing shutdowns. But for a deeper understanding, you may need to know more about logind/systemd than I do.

Long story short, the shutdown info is stored (at least) in a schedule file at `/run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`, the contents of mine as an example were:

```
USEC=1435715559055789
WARN_WALL=1
MODE=poweroff
```

Indicating time (in microseconds, presumably); whether to warn via `wall`, and which mode (cf restart, kexec etc).

Hope this points you in the right direction at least!